# codeigniter mail sending using plesk server 12.5 windows is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, plesk

**error is coming like this.**

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.
```

I am using 7.0.3 PHP version in server.

I tried lot, but not working.

```
`$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'useremail',
    'smtp_pass' => 'yyyyyy',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap'   => TRUE,
    'newline'   => "\r\n"
    ); $this->load->library('email',$config);`

 The mail is going by using port 465. but they created a email from server. what i want is, the mail should go from server email address. Internal mail is working.we are using odin plesk 12.5 server. is it possible to send mail without giving the gmail  username and password? i think need to change the setting in mail server. how to change it? please help me.
```

Comment: What are your mail settings? by which protocol are you trying to send it?

Comment: Can you provide your code here so we can help you further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long duration, plesk customer support gave the smtp hostname. i am using plesk server 12.5 version. here is the code

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'dedrelay.secureserver.net',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap'   => TRUE
    );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
```

Comment: Hi, I also face the same problem on Plesk server trying to send mail() by Codeigniter using Gmail, but not a success. If you have any idea about this so pleas share. Because I'm trying from 2 days but still didn't get the solution.